# Error: Not unique table/alias: 'companies' Database (error): 1066

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, e-commerce

I am making an ecommerce website where I have an admin panel to control the site.

While activating filters for categories and products from admin panel, this sql query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT products.product_id) AS products,
       companies.company AS range_name,
       UPPER(SUBSTRING(companies.company, 1, 1)) AS `index`,
       companies.company_id AS range_id,
       'S' AS field_type
FROM products
LEFT JOIN companies ON companies.company_id = products.company_id
INNER JOIN products_categories ON products_categories.product_id = products.product_id
LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.category_id = products_categories.category_id
LEFT JOIN companies AS companies ON companies.company_id = products.company_id
WHERE products.status IN ('A')
  AND products_categories.category_id IN (261)
  AND (categories.usergroup_ids = ''
       OR FIND_IN_SET(0, categories.usergroup_ids)
       OR FIND_IN_SET(1, categories.usergroup_ids))
  AND (products.usergroup_ids = ''
       OR FIND_IN_SET(0, products.usergroup_ids)
       OR FIND_IN_SET(1, products.usergroup_ids))
  AND categories.status IN ('A',
                            'H')
  AND products.status IN ('A')
  AND (companies.status = 'A')
GROUP BY products.company_id
ORDER BY companies.company
```

breaks down and shows me error:

> Not unique table/alias: 'companies' Database (error): 1066

Can anyone help find the error in this query?

Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: You're joining `companies` to itself but the alias used for the second instance is `companies`, which conflicts with the name of the first instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining with **companies** table twice. That is fine but you must alias them differently.

The first join does not alias so it is called the same; **companies**. The second is aliasing but with again the same name **companies**, and that is causing conflict.

Try as a good practice to alias both with different names, for example **companies1** and **companies2** (or even better, any other more meaningful names) and of course update accordingly all your table references in your select, joins, where, group and order.

Comment: A good practice is to use abbreviations for table names, so the SQL query is not so cumbersome.  `c1` and `c2` or `co1` and `co2`.